# Get text from a <th> using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to extract some text from a HTML table

I tried using

```
tblGridHeader.Rows[0].InnerText.ToString()
```

But I'm getting the error of

> "HTMLTableRow" does not support
>   InnerText property.

I also tried InnerHTML, and still no go.

I did try using the cells property, but I'm getting an error of

> Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values.

**Note:** I just tried the cells property on a static table and it worked.  So I guess it's something to do with my table being dynamically populated?

Code from visual studio editor:

```
<div id="divGridHeader" runat="Server" style="width:771px; text-align:left; overflow:hidden; float:left">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="tblGridHeader" runat="Server">
                <tr id="trMonth" runat="Server" class="fixedHeader">
                </tr>   
                <tr id="trDaysOfWeek" runat="Server" class="fixedHeader">                    
                </tr>   
                <tr id="trDaysInMonth" runat="Server" class="fixedHeader">                    
                </tr>
                <tr id="trFteLimit" runat="Server" class="fixedHeader" style="color:Black">                    
                </tr>                                             
            </table>
        </div>
```

Code from browser:

```
<div id="ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_divGridHeader" style="overflow: hidden; width: 771px; text-align: left; float: left;">
<table id="ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_tblGridHeader" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="1085">
<tbody>
<tr id="ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_trMonth" class="fixedHeader">
</tr>
<tr id="ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_trDaysOfWeek" class="fixedHeader">
</tr>
<tr id="ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_trDaysInMonth" class="fixedHeader">
<th id="ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_thDay_10012010120000AM" class="tt" onmouseout="HideToolTip(ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_spnWorkforceToolTip_ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_thDay_10012010120000AM, ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_spnWorkforceToolTipMiddle_ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_thDay_10012010120000AM);" onmouseover="ShowToolTip(ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_spnWorkforceToolTip_ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_thDay_10012010120000AM, ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_spnWorkforceToolTipMiddle_ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_thDay_10012010120000AM, '135px');" style="background-repeat: repeat-x; text-align: center; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: normal; background-image: url(../Images/TitleGradientMiddle.JPG); height: 20px; width: 35px; text-decoration: none;">
</th>
<th id="ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_thDay_10022010120000AM" class="tt" onmouseout="HideToolTip(ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_spnWorkforceToolTip_ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_thDay_10022010120000AM, ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_spnWorkforceToolTipMiddle_ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_thDay_10022010120000AM);" onmouseover="ShowToolTip(ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_spnWorkforceToolTip_ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_thDay_10022010120000AM, ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_spnWorkforceToolTipMiddle_ctl00_cphWorkforceScheduler_thDay_10022010120000AM, '135px');" style="background-repeat: repeat-x; text-align: center; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: normal; background-image: url(../Images/TitleGradientMiddle.JPG); height: 20px; width: 35px; text-decoration: none;">
```

Etc, etc.  I didn't paste everything since there's a lot of  tags.  Please assume that HTML is well formed.

Comment: What's inside the `<td>`? An `<input>` control of some sort, straight text, or something else?

Comment: It's actually a <th>, sorry about that.  Straight text.

Comment: Can you show us the code for how you're populating the table, and when it is called?  I'm guessing you're trying to read it before it's populated.

Comment: @Tim: I'm positive that I'm reading after the table is populated, since the "reading" takes place in a click event, and the button which throws the click event is only shown once the table is populated.

Comment: Well, but in that case you're trying to read it on a different postback than when you wrote it (clicking the button triggers a postback), so the data might not have been re-populated yet . . . maintaining dynamically generated content on postback is sometimes a tricky business.

Comment: In particular, data in the ViewState gets reloaded at the end of the Init phase, but if dynamically generated controls haven't been reloaded by that point in the page lifecycle, it's not going to work right.  But I'm not 100% sure your dynamically generated stuff is going to be in the ViewState anyway, it depends on how you're loading them to begin with.

Comment: The main thing though to keep in mind is the page is rebuilt on each postback.  So one way or another you need to make sure your dynamic content is generated again on postback at some point before your click event handler is called.

Comment: @Tim Goodman: Looks like you are right!  As a solution, I took the dynamic data and put it into a datatable, then used the information from there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have runat="server" to the TD,you can read it in the codebehind

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyProject.UI" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="tdHere" runat="server">This is my content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <asp:Button ID="btnPost" runat="server" Text="Post" onclick="btnPost_Click" />
          <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</form>
</body>  
</html>
```

and im codebehind

```
using System;

namespace MyProject.UI
{
  public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
     }

     protected void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        lblMessage.Text = tdHere.InnerHtml;
     }
  }
}
```

This is from a working example which i tested

Comment: I put the runat="server" on the <tr> tags, but the tr's are saying there's no cells or controls...

Comment: @Idealflip: I updated my answer with a code which works in my machine.Try that

Comment: <th> are dynamically added to my <tr>'s.  I need the text in my <th> tag.  I believe the fact that my <tr> is saying there's no cells present, is the issue.  Do I have to save a table in viewstate or something?

Comment: A majority of answers given are correct, but I'll mark yours as the answer as it seems the most thorough example/answer.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a web guy, but a quick trip to MSDN revealed the [HTMLTableRow.Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablerow.cells%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) property.

Comment: No, I think Ed is right.  tblGridHeader.Rows[0] returns the first row in the table, hence the "HTMLTableRow" message

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I tried the Cells property as well.  But it's saying there's no Cells.

Answer (score 1):

`HTMLTableRow` controls can't contain text, they can only contain other controls. What are you trying to do exactly? Chances are you should be looking at the `Controls` or `Cells` collection of `HTMLTableRow`, and then inspect the text (or further child controls) of its children.

Comment: Hi, I've tried using cells as well.
tables[j].AddCell(tblGridHeader.Rows[0].Cells[0].InnerText.ToString());

But it says the Cell is empty, which it's not.

<table><tbody><tr><th>i want this text</th></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: Since you said it works for a static table, it sounds like you are trying to read the contents of the cell before they exist. Have you actually added the cell to its owner row, and added its contents at the time you're doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
tblGridHeader.Rows[0].Cells[0].InnerText
```

Assuming you want the textual content from the row's first cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
tblGridHeader.Rows[0].Cells[0].InnerText;
```

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't look like it's supported:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablerow.innertext%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Have you tried reading each of the row's cells?

something like this maybe?

```
string rowData;
foreach(HTMLTableCell c in tblGridHeader.Rows[0].Cells)
{
   rowData += c.InnerHtml; //or c.InnerText
}
```

Comment: I tried using the cell property, but I'm having an issue with the rows saying there's no cells.

Comment: Do you not have any `TD` in your `TR`?

Comment: Can you post your HTML?  According to MSDN `Use the HtmlTableCell class to programmatically control the <td> and <th> HTML elements in an HtmlTableRow object.` Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablecell%28v=VS.80%29.aspx